# How delete the sitedev from the url of wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress

I created a website using wordpress but when I access to mywebsite through the url I got like this:

```
www.example.com/sitedev
```

How can I delete sitedev from the url?

Comment: Is the wordpress installed in a directory called sitedev?

Comment: it is installed in the directory sitedev

Comment: login your cpanel and delete your sitedev folder also delete database

Comment: @ShitalMarakana under sitedev I have all the files and directories of my website if I delete them the website will vanished :D

Comment: @NeilKennedy how can I fix this problem

Comment: Hi,
At first move all files and folder out the sitedev folder, I mean set up your wordpress into main directory of the host,not inside the sitedev.
Then go to database and replace this url www.example.com/sitedev with www.example.com in wp_options table.
Then login to your site and replace all urls using "valvate url" plugin.
and also reset your permalink for settings.